# Include error visual studio code "cannot open source file"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to include this header file

```
#include <fmt/printf.h>
```

and I got an error "cannot open source file "fmt/printf.h""
I have tried in my visual studio code running in Windows with the same installed extensions, and it works fine. But it gives me error in Ubuntu.
Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the library that provides that header? I don’t think it’s a standard file

Comment: Which compiler are you using? If you use MSVC, you could enable the latest language standard (`/std:c++latest`) and `#include <format>` instead to get the standard header. Otherwise, you need to install the [`{fmt}`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library first. `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++20` also supports the standard `<format>` header.